# Fail to generate allure-results directory based on JUnit 4

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, junit4, allure

I failed to generate the directory allure-results in my project. I have tried many methods from google(create src/test/resources/allure.properties, set `<resultsDirectory>${project.build.directory}/allure-results</resultsDirectory>` in pom.xml, etc.), but all setting seems not to take effect. I also failed to redirect the result to other directories. It always said *"[ERROR] Directory <project_path>/target/allure-results not found"*.

My command to generate report is

```bash
mvn clean test -Dtest=aaaTestClass  io.qameta.allure:allure-maven:report
```

My pom.xml is like:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>


  <groupId>***</groupId>
  <artifactId>***</artifactId>
  <version>***</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <parent>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
      <version>2.1.4.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
      ...
      <aspectj.version>1.9.9</aspectj.version>
      <allure.version>2.13.9</allure.version>
    </properties>


  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
        <version>Greenwich.SR1</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>

  <dependencies>
    ...
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-platform-launcher</artifactId>
      <version>1.6.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
      <version>${junit-jupiter.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-jupiter-params</artifactId>
      <version>${junit-jupiter.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
      <version>${junit-jupiter.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
      <version>${junit-jupiter.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-platform-engine</artifactId>
      <version>1.7.0</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-platform-commons</artifactId>
      <version>1.7.0</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
      <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
      <version>6.8</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    ...

    <!-- test report dependencies -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
      <artifactId>allure-junit4</artifactId>
      <version>${allure.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
        <configuration>
          <classifier>runnable</classifier>
          <attach>false</attach>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>repackage</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <!--
        <version>${maven.jar.version}</version>
        -->
        <version>2.4</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-jar</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>jar</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>

<!--      <plugin>-->
<!--        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>-->
<!--        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>-->
<!--        <version>2.19.1</version>-->
<!--        <configuration>-->
<!--          <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>-->
<!--          <argLine>-->
<!--            -javaagent:"${settings.localRepository}/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/${aspectj.version}/aspectjweaver-${aspectj.version}.jar"-->
<!--          </argLine>-->
<!--          <systemProperties>-->
<!--            <property>-->
<!--              <name>allure.results.directory</name>-->
<!--              <value>${project.build.directory}/allure-results</value>-->
<!--            </property>-->
<!--          </systemProperties>-->
<!--          <properties>-->
<!--            <property>-->
<!--              <name>listener</name>-->
<!--              <value>io.qameta.allure.junit4.AllureJunit4</value>-->
<!--            </property>-->
<!--          </properties>-->
<!--        </configuration>-->
<!--        <dependencies>-->
<!--          <dependency>-->
<!--            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>-->
<!--            <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>-->
<!--            <version>${aspectj.version}</version>-->
<!--          </dependency>-->
<!--        </dependencies>-->
<!--      </plugin>-->
<!--      <plugin>-->
<!--        <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>-->
<!--        <artifactId>allure-maven</artifactId>-->
<!--        <version>2.10.0</version>-->
<!--        <configuration>-->
<!--          <reportVersion>${allure.version}</reportVersion>-->
<!--          <resultsDirectory>${project.build.directory}/allure-results</resultsDirectory>-->
<!--          <allureDownloadUrl>-->
<!--            https://***/io/qameta/allure/allure-commandline/2.18.1/allure-commandline-2.18.1.zip-->
<!--          </allureDownloadUrl>-->
<!--        </configuration>-->
<!--      </plugin>-->
    </plugins>
  </build>

  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>aaa</id>
      <build>
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.19.1</version>
            <configuration>
              <includes>
                <include>**/aaatest/*Test</include>
              </includes>
              <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
              <argLine>
                -javaagent:"${settings.localRepository}/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/${aspectj.version}/aspectjweaver-${aspectj.version}.jar"
              </argLine>
              <properties>
                <property>
                  <name>listener</name>
                  <value>io.qameta.allure.junit4.AllureJunit4</value>
                </property>
              </properties>

              <systemPropertyVariables>
                <allure.results.directory>${project.build.directory}/allure-results</allure.results.directory>
              </systemPropertyVariables>

            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
              <dependency>
                <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
                <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
              </dependency>
            </dependencies>
          </plugin>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
            <artifactId>allure-maven</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.2</version>
            <configuration>
              <reportVersion>${allure.version}</reportVersion>
              <resultsDirectory>${project.build.directory}/allure-results</resultsDirectory>
              <allureDownloadUrl>
                https://***/io/qameta/allure/allure-commandline/2.18.1/allure-commandline-2.18.1.zip
              </allureDownloadUrl>
            </configuration>
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
      </build>
    </profile>
    <profile>
      <id>bbb</id>
      <build>
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.19.1</version>
            <configuration>
              <includes>
                <include>**/bbbtest/*Test</include>
              </includes>
              <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
            </configuration>
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
      </build>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
</project>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my project, I just add this dependency to fix this issue:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
    <artifactId>surefire-junit4</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0-M7</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

The profile setup seems to be a mixture of Junit4 and JUnit5 configuration for Allure reports. Clean this up first, suggest the below for the first profile based on Junit4:

```xml
<profiles>
  <profile>
    <id>aaa</id>
    <build>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.19.1</version>
          <configuration>
            <includes>
              <include>**/aaatest/*Test</include>
            </includes>
            <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
            <argLine>
              -javaagent:"${settings.localRepository}/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/${aspectj.version}/aspectjweaver-${aspectj.version}.jar"
            </argLine>
            <properties>
              <property>
                <name>listener</name>
                <value>io.qameta.allure.junit4.AllureJunit4</value>
              </property>
            </properties>
          </configuration>
          <dependencies>
            <dependency>
              <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
              <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
              <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
            </dependency>
          </dependencies>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </build>
  </profile>
</profiles>
```

The configuration should generate the results in the default location of `<project_path>/target/allure-results`

There also is an issue with the `mvn` command. The first part of the command is `mvn clean` it will ensure that any existing `target` directory is removed before the next part of the command, in this case `test`.

The command as noted above is a two part command, the second effectively being `mvn io.qameta.allure:allure-maven:report`.

In summary, both `mvn` commands are being executed at the same time:

- one that removes the `target` directory(`mvn clean`) or awaiting to create it (`mvn test`)
- second that wants to generate a report in the `target` directory that does not exist or awaiting to be created by the above

Also to note that the second part of the command could also cause an exception even if the `target` directory did exist. As no allure results would have been created as the `mvn test` still needs to execute a test result / complete the test execution suite

The requirement here is a `mvn` cli command that will run both commands consequentially, use the `&&` syntax like this:

```
mvn clean test -Dtest=aaaTestClass && mvn allure:report
```

This will run the test suite to completion and then generate the report

The report should generated in the following location:

```
<project_path>/target/site/allure-maven/index.html
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. But the dir allure-results can't be generated even after "mvn clean test -Dtest=aaaTestClass". Any more suggestion?

Comment: Looked at our projects, previously using junit4, now using junit5 and carried out a diff. This has changed my answer, please see amended answer above.